# (Scala TYPE-SAFETY) take a string as a parameter only if it has .txt extension in it else compile error it?

Tags: scala, types

I'm thinking if its possible to create some sort of data structure that would take a string as a parameter and if that string does not contains .txt or something like that it would give me a compile error?

I can be specific on my problem - I am trying to take a file as a parameter(Source) to a function but I am told that currently I am passing any kind of file and it only should take text files so it is not done correctly. How do i approach this?
-Thanks!! ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that String is coming from somewhere other than the code base (web request, cmd line), you'll need to pass that String to something that accepts Strings. Thus you'll have a point at which you're converting a String to your special filename datatype. So I can't see any way you'll be able to protect against some kind of runtime check.

If you want a runtime check that will avoid an error, you could return an `Option`, returning `None` if the String isn't a valid filename

Comment: Yeah, probably using Option is what I am looking for. Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is not a problem. The big question is should you do it though. If your code is a library of sorts then under certain circumstances this might make sense. Check out [Uri.uri](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/53f5c5f280287df23ef7c9914f1cbae014e04e3b/core/src/main/scala/org/http4s/Uri.scala#L272) from the http4s project

In your case the implementation could look something like this:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

class Macros(val c: Context) {
  import c.universe._
  def txtFile(fileName: c.Expr[String]): Tree =
    fileName.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(s: String)) if s.endsWith(".txt") =>
        fileName.tree
      case _ =>
        c.abort(
          c.enclosingPosition,
          s"Supplied parameter is not a text file"
        )
    }
}

object MyObject {
  def txtFile(fileName: String): String = macro Macros.txtFile
}
```

You'd use this like:

```
val x: String = txtFile("abc.tx") // Fails to compile
val y: String = txtFile("abc.txt") // Compiles
```

Again, it can be done, but you probably want to go with `Option` :-)

Comment: Interesting... This gives me ```error: not found: value Macros ```

Comment: Is there a short explanation of how this checks unknown strings at compile time, if that's how it works?

Comment: Not sure about the error. I'm using Scala 2.12.6. In dotty I believe macros are no longer available. The OP asked for a compile time check so the string (i.e. some sort of config value) needs to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) library:

```
type TxtSuffix = EndsWith[W.`".txt"`.T]
type TxtFile = String Refined TxtSuffix
```

In order to construct a `TxtFile`, you need to give it a string that ends with ".txt":

```
val file: TxtFile = refineMV[TxtSuffix]("some.pdf") // compiler error
error: Predicate failed: "some.pdf".endsWith(".txt")
```